# How to get drafted by Philadelphia in NBA2K14 My Career PS4?

Tags: nba2k14

I've been drafted to them before, but I don't remember what stats I got. Every time I try I get interviewed by some teams from 4-8 picks. Any suggestions on what stats I need to get to get drafted by them?

Comment: Sorry for spamming with these 2K14 questions..

Comment: Is "my career" a part of the games title? I was going to edit the question to, "what determines which teams want to draft me in nba2k14?" In an effort to get more eyeballs on your question. But I dont know enough about that game to safely assume.

Comment: No, it's a mode in NBA2K14.

Answer (score 1):

Getting 12/14 points and 9/10 assists and 1/2 rebounds and a 1 or couple of steals will get you drafted by them if you be nice in the interview.